# How to convert the JSON date with to_date function

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, json, date

**How to convert the specific string Aug 6, 2018 3:17:11 PM with the function to_date?**

That string is a result of a Java parsing mechanism for JSON. I would like to be able to recover it directly from oracle.

> My real problem is much more comprehensive that looks to be. It evolves the APEX_JSON usage, but it is not the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
select to_date('Aug 6, 2018 3:17:11 PM', 'MON DD, YYYY HH:MI:SS PM') from dual;

TO_DATE('AUG6,20183
-------------------
2018-08-06 15:17:11
```

[Datetime Format Models](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements004.htm#i34924)

Comment: Balazs are there no differences between `PM` and `AM` in the oracle datetime format models?